# Angular CLI with Hybrid app ng-build

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng-upgrade, angular-upgrade

I'm currently upgrading an AngularJS app to an Angular app, using Angular CLI.

My problem is that when I build the app using `ng build`, it would copy all the files to the `dist` folder but will ignore all the AngularJS files.
For all the js files, my solution was to add them to the `scripts` array in the `angular-cli.json`. 
Now, I just need to handle the html files. For the Angular app, angular cli will handle them automatically for me, but the AngularJS ones will stay outside the `dist` folder. A solution I came up with, was to add them to the `assets` array.
So basically I have two questions:

1. Is there a way where I can tell angular cli to build all `.html` files from a certain folder? something like that: `"assets": [
   "app/ng1/.*html" 
   ]`
2. Is this best practice? or is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for my first question:
In the `assets` array, instead of putting the plain path of the `html` files, I used glob:
`{ "glob": "**/*.html", "input": "./app/ng1", "output": "./app/ng1" }`
while using `**` will pick all the sub-directories in `/app/ng1`